# Как в Python правильнее вызывать методы других классов - напрямую или через их экземпляры?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, instance

В процессе изучения последнего принципа SOLID в контексте Python (вдруг это важно) наткнулся на пример, в котором **вызов метода другого класса** можно выполнять как **напрямую**, так и через **создание его экземпляра**.

```
class Line:
    def draw(self):
        print('line')

class Painter:
    def painting(self, class_painter):
        class_painter.draw(self)

class Painter2:
    def painting(self, class_painter):
        class_painter().draw()

p_class_method = Painter()
p_class_method.painting(Line)
p_instance_method = Painter2()
p_instance_method.painting(Line)
```

Результат будет одинаковый, но не нарушаю ли я при этом какой-нибудь принцип программирования одним из способов? Какие есть подводные камни при таких вызовах? Какой вариант считается правильным в реальных программах? В примере был второй вариант, с созданием экземпляра. Но не считается ли плохой практикой создание новых объектов без необходимости?

Вопрос может и странный, но я только изучаю программирование и не знаком с общепринятыми практиками и подводными камнями в разных вариантах

Comment: Результат будет не одинаковый, потому что в `class_painter.draw(self)` вы передаёте экземпляр **чужого** класса, и вызванный метод имеет полное право испугаться от неожиданности и упасть с ошибкой

Comment: @andreymal а можно для самых маленьких и тупых? сам результат то как раз будет одинаковый, тут процесс разный. в какой именно ситуации метод может упасть с ошибкой?

Comment: Ну например если в классе `Line` будет метод `get_length` и метод `draw` попытается вызвать этот метод — упадёт с ошибкой, потому что в классе `Painter` такого метода не будет

Comment: @andreymal Не сразу, но вроде понял о чем вы. Видимо в реальной разработке используется способ через создание нового экземпляра `class_painter().draw()`?